# WebApp ignores patched perl pm file

Tags: perl

I never really came in touch with perl before, so I really hope, this is a real newbie question and I can solve the problem pretty quick...

We've one perl based web application installed on a windows 2003 server environment. The installed version contains a bug and I know *where* to apply the patch. Basically: I have carefully changed two lines in one of the web apps `pm` files.

To my surprise, the file change is ignored and I still get the same error messages with references to the old version of the file - clearly identifiable by the line numbers.

I've cleared the browser caches, restarted the web application (including apache) - no luck.

Now I think/hope that this is some kind of perl feature, but I even don't know enough of that language to ask google the right questions. [One tutorial](http://world.std.com/~swmcd/steven/perl/module_mechanics.html) said, that perl is an interpreted language and that changes to source files are effective immediately. This isn't true for my site...

Are there some more caches/files I have to touch or delete in order to make my changes effective?

Comment: <nitpick>"One tutorial said, that perl is an interpreted language and that changes to source files are effective immediately. This isn't true for my site..."
That isn't really true. Changing the source code won't change your program - Perl can be self-aware (open+0;<0>), but not self-modifing (easily, anyway). Once the code is compiled away into opcodes, the source doesn't matter much.</nitpick>

Comment: @Hugmeir - could be a hint - maybe a *compiled* version of this file is somewhere cached/loaded/stored? Can I find and remove it?

Comment: I'm talking out of my turf here, so take everything with a giant grain of salt, but I wouldn't think so. Stopping the server and/or the Perl interpreter should make those 'cached' versions go away. This might not apply for webservers, though. Maybe you could retag the question?

Comment: @Hugmeir - I found the needle in the hackstay and - yes, it hurt ;) See my cw answer below.

Comment: Perl doesn't generally store compiled binaries on disk. There is an experimental module that lets you do this, but last I heard it was pretty unstable and not recommended for day-to-day use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your Perl is actually using the latest version of said pm file? There is no other version somewhere else included which is getting used?

1. Take a look at [@INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)
2. Step through your programming using a debugger
3. Sprinkle warnings around the code and see if it gets called.

Comment: As an addition, make sure that the directory where the new version resides is the first element of @INC; Keep in mind that the script's directory is the last place Perl looks for a module. For a quick fix,
BEGIN { unshift @INC, '/path/to/module/dir' }

Comment: Thanks - but I neither have knowledge nor tools to debug perl, inspect `@inc` or add log instructions. I did a file search for said `.pm` file and this changed one is the only one on that machine.

Comment: If you can afford to break the app for a second, add `die "XXXXX\n";` at the beginning of the module. Then Perl should barf up the error if it picked up the correct module.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved and the solution was outside perl - thanks for your patience.

The web application contained some javascript / css caching. After

1. deleting the caches (`js-chache`, `css-cache`)
2. clearing the browser cache
3. restarting Internet Explorer (**!**)

it started working again. Don't ask me why...